# Wrong outcome for Condition Operators to check in if..else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Functionality:**

There are four different fields in a detail page. In which, there is a set of 2 fields each that needs to be filled before the user can navigate to the next page.

Furthermore, there is a conditional check to ensure that a set of 2 fields from 2 sets are filled before allowing users to navigate to the next page.

Hence, the flow is as follows:

[EITHER]

> SET A :   dropdownmenu_A  & inputTEXTfield_A

is filled

[OR]

> SET B: dropdownmenu_B  & inputTEXTfield_B

is filled.

The conditional check will allow user to navigate to the next page.

If either one of them is not filled, it will not allow the user to progress.

***Issue:***

At this point, users are still able to submit and navigate from the current page to the next page even though the mandatory fields are not filled. This is the logic that I used to check (pseudo code)

```
if((dropdownmenu_A is empty && inputTEXTfield_A is empty) OR 
   (dropdownmenu_B is empty && inputTEXTfield_B is empty))
```

Hence, the following condition should actually check if the fields are empty or filled.

Where has my operator logic gone wrong?

***Code:***

```js
// On Submit

function SubmitReceiptDetails() {
  idleTime = 0;

  //Check for Input Field
  if (($.trim($("#dropDownShops_1").val()) == "" && 
       $.trim($("#ReceiptField_1").val()) == "") || 
      ($.trim($("#dropDownShops_2").val()) == "" && 
       $.trim($("#ReceiptField_2").val()) == "")) {

    console.log("Receipt_Field_Error wrong");
    alert("Your field is not filled");
  } else {
    $('#PageA').fadeOut();
    $('#PageB').fadeIn();
  }
}
```

```html
<form>

  <!-- DropDown Menu to choose Participating Outlet -->
  <select id="dropDownShops_1">
    <option value="None" selected="Selected">Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="ReceiptField_1" style="z-index=10; position:absolute; top:390px; left:858px; height:58px; width:265px; outline:0; border: 0; font-size:25px; font-family:'Gothic'; color:#765725; background: transparent;" autofocus>

  <select id="dropDownShops_2">
    <option value="None" selected="Selected">Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="ReceiptField_2" style="z-index=10; position:absolute; top:585px; left:858px; height:58px; width:265px; outline:0; border: 0; font-size:25px; font-family:'Gothic'; color:#765725;  background: transparent;">

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the === operator instead?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - your snippet does not execute - e.g. you have not assigned the validation to the submit event

Comment: have you tried logging the `.val()` of all of your fields when it returns true so you can see what values have been returned? if so, what are they returning?

Comment: `value="None" !== value=""`

Comment: All 4 fields must be filled?

Comment: @magnat nope, not all4, it is either "dropDownShops_1" && "ReceiptField_1" must be filled OR  "dropDownShops_2" && "ReceiptField_2" must be filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your option element has a value of 'None', when checking this with .val() it will never be empty. Also instead of:

```
if (($.trim($("#dropDownShops_1").val()) == "" && 
     $.trim($("#ReceiptField_1").val()) == "") || 
    ($.trim($("#dropDownShops_2").val()) == "" && 
     $.trim($("#ReceiptField_2").val()) == "")) {
}
```

Try this:

```
if (($.trim($("#dropDownShops_1").val()) == "" || 
     $.trim($("#ReceiptField_1").val()) == "") && 
    ($.trim($("#dropDownShops_2").val()) == "" ||
     $.trim($("#ReceiptField_2").val()) == "")) {
}
```

I tested it and it works. 
Html option element:

```
<option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Shops ...</option>
```

Comment: But your operational logic is that either "dropDownShops_1" OR "ReceiptField_1" is empty  AND ""dropDownShops_2"" OR "ReceiptField_2" is empty  and not either "dropDownShops_1" AND "ReceiptField_1" is empty  AND ""dropDownShops_2"" AND "ReceiptField_2"?? But, yes works though but just that it is either  "dropDownShops_1" OR "ReceiptField_1"  per set that is checked

Comment: I don't think you get it:

Comment: Because you are checking for empty values it works, because if one of the two in a set is empty it returns true, but if none in either set is empty it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in if statement

```
if (($.trim($("#dropDownShops_1").val()) == "" &&
     $.trim($("#ReceiptField_1").val()) == "") ||
    ($.trim($("#dropDownShops_2").val()) == "" &&
    $.trim($("#ReceiptField_2").val()) == ""))
```

this should be like

```
 if ($.trim($("#dropDownShops_1").val() !== "" &&
       $.trim($("#ReceiptField_1").val() !== "" ||
     $.trim($("#dropDownShops_2").val() !== "" &&
       $.trim($("#ReceiptField_2").val() !== "") {

               GO TO NEXT PAGE

   } else {
                SHOW ERROR
    }
```

Or

```
 if (($.trim($("#dropDownShops_1").val() == "" ||
       $.trim($("#ReceiptField_1").val() == "") &&
     ($.trim($("#dropDownShops_2").val() !== "" ||
       $.trim($("#ReceiptField_2").val() !== "")) {

               SHOW ERROR

   } else {
               GO TO NEXT PAGE 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems that the unselected option has value of "None",so `$("yourselector").val()` returns "None" and not an empty string.